# JPEG hex text to Image?

Tags: jpeg

I have an old database that has images in it that I want to extract. The images are in a column labelled jpg and have format :

ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000001 00010000 fffe002e 496e7465 6c285229 204a5045 47204c69 62726172 792c2076 65727369 6f6e205b 312e3531 2e31332e 34355d00 ffdb0043 00080606 07060508 ...

I believe this is JPEG encoding. How do I turn this into a regular image? I tried copy pasting it into a text editor and naming the file image.jpg, but it won't open. Not sure what I'm missing. Is there a solution in python?

Comment: That is probably just how your dbms interprets the data, what is the data type of the column?

Comment: So the mdb file wouldn't open on ms access on my work computer because it said it was too old of a file type or something. On my home computer, which is a mac, I opened it using a program called MDB ACCDB Viewer. I think the column type is file, because it represents it as 'Unknown File 1.2MB'. When I double click it I see the hexadecimal.

Comment: Since it's most likely just a file type (called OLE Object on MS Access) just search for how you can view or get the file, if you're doing a program just search how to read that data type in the language you're using.

Comment: You must use a hexadecimal editor to copy and paste the values you see and then save the file, instead of using a text editor for copy-pasting.